# How to create a scikit-learn pipeline that applies z-score and cross-validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline, cross-validation

I am trying to normalize my data at each step of the cross-validation and I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612944/how-to-use-scikits-preprocessing-normalization-along-with-cross-validation)

As suggested, I went to the scikit-learn documentation and found this example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), svm.SVC(C=1))
cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)
```

This looks indeed like what I am trying to achieve, however, my intention is to use a [z-scorer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) instead of the StandardScaler, so I tried this:

```
clf = make_pipeline(stats.zscore(), DecisionTreeClassifier())
```

But I get an error saying this:

```
TypeError: zscore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

What should be the argument of zscore()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are several ways of using custom functionality in `sklearn` pipelines — I think [FunctionTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) could fit your case.

Create a transformer that uses `zscore` and pass the transformer to `make_pipeline` instead of calling `zscore` directly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!